# CSS stack cards

Tags: css

I am looking for a way to stack card images one over another with CSS:
[image: Stack]

My code:

```
<ul class="stack">
    <li class="card"><img src="4h.png"/></li>
    <li class="card"><img src="9c.png"/></li>
    <li class="card"><img src="5c.png"/></li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to make it with just CSS?

Comment: position relative or absolute and z-index (lowest index at the bottom)

Comment: have you heard of `z-index`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: you can move the cards using `left` property

Comment: @SimonNovak try this https://jsfiddle.net/xff2o5dp/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use margin or padding to move the cards to the left.

[Here is an example codepen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/avzBMR)

```css
.card {
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

#card1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#card2 {
  background-color: red;
}

#card3 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="card1" class="card" />
<div id="card2" class="card" />
<div id="card3" class="card" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to give your cards `absolute` positioning. For each card in the HTML, use inline CSS to assign a `left` position and a `z-index` position in the stack (e.g. 0 for bottom card, 1 for the card above it, etc.). Make sure you remove your list bullets if you see them.

```css
.stack {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.card {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<ul class="stack">
    <li class="card" style="left:25px;z-index:0;"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/1/150/200"></li>
    <li class="card" style="left:50px;z-index:1;"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/2/150/200"></li>
    <li class="card" style="left:75px;z-index:2;"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/3/150/200"></li>
</ul>
```